# Devise multiple pathes for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to have two different routes for devise:

- localhost:3000/login - standart devise auth
- localhost:3000/api/login - auth for api calls using another, not standart controller **/api/sessions_controller**

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }  
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  devise_for :users,
             path: '',
             defaults: { format: :json },
             path_names: {
               sign_in: 'login',
               sign_out: 'logout',
              },
              controllers: { sessions: 'api/sessions' }
end
```

**rails routes | grep sessio**

```
new_user_session         GET     /login(.:format)  devise/sessions#new
user_session             POST    /login(.:format) devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session     DELETE  /logout(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy
new_api_user_session     GET     /api/login(.:format) api/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
api_user_session         POST    /api/login(.:format) api/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
destroy_api_user_session DELETE  /api/logout(.:format) api/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

**api/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

respond_to :json

private

def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
  render json: resource
end

def respond_to_on_destroy
  head :no_content
end
end
```

That code looks fine for me, but when i try to send POST-request to my **localhost:3000/api/login** with auth credentials it returns error:

> {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}

If i comment out my default devise routes and move api routes from api namespace everything works fine, post-request return me json with resource:
**routes.rb**

```
#devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }  
devise_for :users,
             path: 'api',
             defaults: { format: :json },
             path_names: {
               sign_in: 'login',
               sign_out: 'logout',
              },
              controllers: { sessions: 'api/sessions' }

namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  ...
end
```

Why that happened? What i'm missing?

Comment: In your final implementation, you want to have two different routes for `devise` right?  `localhost:3000/login` and `localhost:3000/api/login`, at the same time.

Comment: Yes, first for standart db-auth, second - jwt-auth for api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }
devise_scope :user do
   post 'api/login', to: 'api/sessions#create', as: 'api_login', defaults: {format: :json}
   get 'api/logout', to: 'api/sessions#destroy', as: 'api_logout', defaults: {format: :json}
end
```

It's similiar with Guilermo Aguirre answer.

Answer (score 7):

Having this in my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
    path: '',
    path_names: {
      sign_in: 'login',
      sign_out: 'logout'
    }

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :users do
      devise_scope :user do
        post 'login', to: 'sessions#create', defaults: { format: :json }
      end
    end
  end    
end
```

`rails routes` outputs:

```
                                   Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                                              Controller#Action
                         new_user_session GET        /login(.:format)                                         devise/sessions#new
                             user_session POST       /login(.:format)                                         devise/sessions#create
                     destroy_user_session DELETE     /logout(.:format)                                        devise/sessions#destroy
                       api_v1_users_login POST       /api/v1/users/login(.:format)                            api/v1/users/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
```

Making the POST request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login` works as expected
And now accessing `http://localhost:3000/login` redirects to the default devise login page, and login works as it should. The problem was you can't have the same `devise_for` twice. You can have `devise_for :users` and `devise_for :admin_users` but not twice for the same, in this case `:users`.

Comment: I have already removed `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!`, it doesn't matter

Comment: Your answer is my second case, where there is single devise login route through api. But i need to have two routes: `localhost:3000/login` and `localhost:3000/api/login` with different devise-controllers.

Comment: I'm sorry that I missunderstood your question initially. I have now edited the answer, now I think this is what you want, of course correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thx for your answer, i done similiar thing, look at my answer.

Comment: For me it wat not obvious that i can't have two devise_for :users )

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem now and came up with the same solution. However, when I use `devise-jwt` for api, it seems the Authorization header is not sent back on a successful login as it is when I use it for a controller set up via `devise_for`.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your initial route definition, you're already in the API namespace, so when you define your controller, you don't need

```
'api/sessions'
```

But just

```
'sessions'
```

I think this will make the request hit the correct controller, which means your authenticate_admin! method won't fire, which it is at the moment, resulting in your auth issue.

Comment: in that case i got error "uninitialized constant SessionsController"